# How do I bring Unity interface in-front of all other windows?

Tags: unity

As Ubuntu is switching to unity in 11.04 it seemed reasonable to try it on my 10.10 desktop.  Unfortunately, when I launch it I see the icons down the left-hand side but the rest of the unity interface if obscured by any other windows I have open.

For example, when I click the Applications icon in unity if I have another window open it doesn't seem to do anything until I minimize the active window revealing the application list in the background.  It's the same for the menu that appear when I right-click on on icon.

What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you running Unity? You shouldn't be using the unity binary (/usr/bin/unity), as that is for testing only, rather you should be logging into the Unity session from the login screen (choose your name and then choose the session from the list on the bottom panel).

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that and it seems to be working much better!